# WPF Toolkit AutoCompleteBox is missed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

There many examples with using WPF Toolkit AutoCompleteBox, 
i.e. http://www.broculos.net/2014/04/wpf-autocompletebox-autocomplete-text.html

but it's missed in current version wpftoolkit.codeplex.com in documentation, and not founded in assembly after installing package.

Is it deleted or migrate into another control ?

Comment: Have you added namespace correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not there because you're using

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com

The site you mention (http://www.broculos.net/2014/04/wpf-autocompletebox-autocomplete-text.html) tells you to use

https://wpf.codeplex.com/